# Are there any objections to Winter Bash hats?

Tags: discussion

Winter Bash is coming soon. Each SE site can choose not to participate. I can't think of any reason why we wouldn't participate, particularly since each user has the option to turn the feature off and the hats will disappear.

I'm planning to tell the powers that be that ELL is "in" unless someone here presents a convincing argument against participating.

---

To those who may be new to the Stack Exchange: Winter Bash is a season where your avatar pictures may start wearing hats. Some hats are easy to earn, and some take more effort. You can choose which of your hats sits atop your avatar from the ones you have earned. Some use the hats as incentive to do more on SE, by trying to earn as many as they can. (Personally, I just go with the flow and then I watch what happens.)

Comment: Yippee!  Hats, hats!

Comment: Oh awesome! I've seen these notifications a few places but wasn't sure if they applied to beta sites :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We love hats!  Give us hats!  Hats, hats, and more hats.

Answer (score 2):

Hats, hats, hats. We love hats. We want hats.
Hats, hats, hats. Where are hats? I want hats.
Hats, hats, hats. I want that Chatty Cat Hat!
Not just that hat, but all the hats. I love hats!

Answer (score -3):

We hate hats!  Argh!  keep those darn filthy things away from our sparkly, pristine heads.

Comment: Hats serve everyone: they provide joy to genial petasophiles and an occasion for whining to peevish misopetasists.

Comment: I didn't know you were bald!